# How to change style of no classed div?

Tags: html, css

I have this nested html

i want to access the second sibling, whose parent is div of class "x"

i tried using

```css
.x div:nth-child(2) {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <div>.....</div>
  <div> The One i want to change it's style</div>
</div>
```

The code works.

Comment: _"but didn't work"_ - yes it does, this here is nothing but your code plus extra red background added: https://jsfiddle.net/vhnedp8k/

Comment: your code is correct. The problem might be that it's being overwritten but some different css rule without you knowing it. To test that add !important at the end of each property. e.g try this one .x div:nth-child(2) { background: blue !important }

Comment: @CBroe chillout man, i just used it in the wrong file, i noticed. It's just was my first time using that, that's why i thought it was incorrect.

Comment: @Abdel-Rahman in that case I suggest you delete the question as its not reproducible.

Comment: @kiranvj i tried deleting it several times, stackoverflow rejected it since i got 2 answers on it...so i just edited it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its working, please see below. I have also added a child selector `>` . But without that also it should work.

```css
.x > div:nth-child(2) {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <div>.....</div>
  <div> The One i want to change it's style</div>
  <div>third div</div>
</div>
```